# How do you get Ghost while waiting for the funicular in Picus?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

So here I am waiting for a "funicular" and I've got all these mines and a cute little robot with machine guns guarding the doors, but for some reason I can't get the ghost award. The radar doesn't go red or say hostile. No one sees me. Everyone dies within about 3 seconds. I've tried different ways for about an hour without getting it.

Did anyone actually get ghost here? Is it even possible? If you did, how?

Comment: Side note that isn't big enough for an answer: you lose Ghost if any guard sees any other guard who is unconscious or dead. I blew Ghost for at least two out of three missions because I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To my recollection, I did get Ghost in this room. To do so, as soon as I hit the switch I activated stealth and crouch-walked into the nearest hole in the floor, where a floorboard had been removed. I hid inside this vent area until the funicular finally arrived, and then activated stealth, went into the funicular and closed it to complete the objective. No one was harmed, and nobody saw me.

Comment: ... why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 1):

I got it too; I was quite fortunate to have several gas mines + templates.

In total I laid down four mines. One gas mine at both entrances, and concussion mines just to the right side of where the closest mine would have been. I then just crouched behind the block and managed to stealth into the funicular. I did it my first attempt without reloading, so it was quite an easy one.

If you don't have gas mines, I think the vent strategy would work best.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the mines or the turret... Just barricade the left doorway with a tall box (swing the door open first) and block the right-hand door with the vending machine.

> cute little robot with machine guns guarding the doors

I haven't tested, but it sounds likely that if guards get involved in a shootout with your turret, it's the same as if they got into a shootout with you, therefore you lose the Ghost bonus.

Comment: Barricade... that's smart. But won't the guy off to the left see you through the windows if I use the vending machine to block the door. I guess there are those storage rooms full of boxes to use...

Comment: The last two times I tried, enemies stood exactly where they spawned the whole time. Only one was near the windows, and he didn't try very hard to get a good look. Just went through the vent and did a takedown, then spent the rest of the time pacing the lobby.